# Any good gem to accumulate Statistics (JSON) on a daily basis and present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, graph, statistics

I have an API call that returns a JSON format for live statistics - Things like number of people who registered, signed in, performed action a, etc.

Now, I would like to have a history with some presentable graphs. 
My plan is to hit the api once a day to get the json and save each result in an activerecord table.

Is there any better suggested way for this. Also, any gem recommendations to make my life easy.

1. Create an activerecord model to with the report fields and a date column
2. Hit API to get JSON once a day and populate above table
3. Plot the above table with various possible dimentions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) would be something to check out then. It can take the JSON and present good graphs.

It was the easiest I found so far (and still not great). Once with that you can set up a CRON job with the `whenever` gem to do the data pull once a day.

Comment: Thanks for that.. I'll still keep the question open so that I can get to see what other people have used. This problem is quite a common problem. I would be curious to see what people use